# Assign first-of-type child's height to parent

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have this form:

```
<form method="get" id="filterForK2ModuleForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="option">
    <input type="hidden" name="view">
    <input type="hidden" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" name="mid">
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid">

    <div id="filter_field_33" class="field_checkbox" style="height: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div id="filter_field_4" class="field_radio" style="height: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div id="filter_field_11" class="field_radio" style="height: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div id="filter_field_22" class="field_checkbox" style="height: 50px;">
    </div>
</form>
```

And want to assign the height of the first-child div (it has variable ID) to it's parent. (on the website, there is a button to set the height back to 100%)

But when i try to write the height in a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var filterheight = $("#filterForK2ModuleForm div:first-of-type").height();
});
</script>
```

console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined`.

Can you help me to accomplish this easy task?

Comment: It's working fine please double check you code - https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/3qemzdhy/

Comment: decide between jQuery or $, in some cases on will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldnt manage to do it with jquery, but this javascript works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
            var filterheight = document.getElementById('filterForK2ModuleForm').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].clientHeight;
            document.getElementById("filterForK2ModuleForm").style.height = (filterheight + 'px');
    }
</script>
```